# iterative replace string with n-array while maintaining order

Tags: php

Basically, I would like to build a function that will take in N-parameters (or a variable-length array, whatever) and pump out an array of strings much like this..

```
doTheThing("First", "Second", "Third");

array(
First_Second_Third
First_Second_0
First_0_Third
First_0_0
0_Second_Third
0_Second_0
0_0_Third
0_0_0
)
```

The order of the results is important. I think I know how I would do this if I had a static-length array, but I can't get to work where I can use variable-length arrays.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?

Comment: Well its just a case of trial and error. Code something, test it, Fix any issues, thet test again. ___Its called development for a reason___

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's what i came up with

```
function doTheThing(array $params){
    $set_len =  count($params);
    $result = [];
    $result_len = 1 << $set_len;
    for ($c = 0; $c < $result_len; $c++){
        $pattern = str_split(sprintf("%0{$set_len}s", decbin($c)), 1);
        $result[] = implode('_', array_map(
            function($input, $flag){ return $flag ? 0 : $input;},
            $params, $pattern
        ));
    }
    return $result;
}

var_dump(doTheThing(['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five']));
```

Comment: Fantastic solution and works exactly as expected. Many thanks. After running through it, I think I grok what you did.